# Set Anaconda as default Python in .tcshrc file

Tags: python, anaconda, tcsh

On the advice of my supervisor, I switched my shell over from bash to tcsh. However, I'm having trouble getting my Anaconda install to set to be the default python in tcsh as it was in bash.

I need to know the .tcshrc equivalent of

> export PATH="/home/george/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

which the Anaconda installer automatically placed in my .bashrc file. I have searched for ages on Google for the right syntax, but whatever I enter in the .tcshrc file doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the equivalent in the .cshrc file:

```
set path = (/home/georg/anaconda3/bin $path)
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the PATH for a C Shell(tcsh) you would need to set it with the following syntax:

```
setenv PATH $PATH\:<path to anaconda/bin>
```

By default Anaconda would store it in Linux under:

/home/username/anaconda/bin

Mac OS X:

/Users/username/anaconda/bin

Windows:

C:\Users\username\Anaconda

C:\Users\username\Anaconda\Scripts

EDIT:
To make this persistent in Mac OS X I created ~/.login and added the above command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, when I restart the terminal after editing this file and type python, I still get the existing python 2.7 interpreter come up by default... when Anaconda automatically edited my .bashrc when I originally installed it, I could type python into the terminal and get the anaconda install's interpreter by default.

Comment: To make this persistent in Mac OS X I created ~/.login and added the above command.